# Replace index of a DataFrame with another index from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, series

I have two Data Frames 'nai_data' and 'table' and I want to use the index column of 'nai_data' as index for 'table'. I have tried `table.index = nai_data.index`. They are of the same length, but the problem is that when I load the 'table', it puts one of the values as a header and that's why the lengths now do not match. How do I prevent pandas putting that one value into the header? (I am reading the Excel file, see below:) I know it can be done easily when reading a text file with `header = None` but is there any equivalent with `pd.ExcelFile.parse`?

Data Frame 'nai_data':
[image: Data Frame 'nai_data']

Data Frame 'table':

[image]

Comment: Can you add [MVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If the are the same size you can do `A.index = B.index`

Comment: Add few lines of the data you are using, and your attempts. Not just summary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with parameter `header=None`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None)
print df
#            0           1
#0        col1        col2
#1  10-05-2011  31-05-2011
#2  05-10-2011  14-12-2011
```

Function [pandas.ExcelFile.parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) has parameter `header=None` too.

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
table = excel_file.parse('Sheet1', header=None)
print table
#            0           1
#0        col1        col2
#1  10-05-2011  31-05-2011
#2  05-10-2011  14-12-2011
```

You can use parameter `skiprows` too.